# Does `try... except Exception as e` catch every possible exception?

Tags: python, exception

In Python 2, are all exceptions that can be `raise`d required to inherit from Exception?

That is, is the following sufficient to catch any possible exception:

```
try:
   code()
except Exception as e:
   pass
```

or do I need something even more general like

```
try:
   code()
except:
   pass
```

Comment: No. But unless you want to f*ck things up, don't do either.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What if I need my program to continue no matter what happens in `code()`?

Comment: Then you're using the wrong platform.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the first variant you'll catch "all built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), and should catch user defined exceptions ("all user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class").

For example, the first variant will not catch user-pressed Control-C (KeyboardInterrupt), but the second will.

Comment: So is it safe to say the second one catches everything?

Comment: @jpp, yes - "An expression-less except clause, if present, must be last; it matches any exception." https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#except